# python looping over specified array elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I am using numpy.ndenumerate for array element iteration:

```
a = np.ones((10,10,10))
for (x,y,z), value in numpy.ndenumerate(a):
    do stuff with x,y,z and value
```

How can I iterate only over specified element values? For example if the array is binary, how do I iterate over all ones?

Currently I am using something like:

```
specified = np.nonzero(a) #or np.where(a == some_value)
for i in xrange(np.count_nonzero(a)):
    do stuff with x,y,z = specified[0][i], specified[1][i], specified[2][i] 
    and value = a[x,y,z]
```

This is obviously pretty ugly and I am shure there is a nice short way.

Comment: The nice way to operate on just the 'ones' of an array is with a boolean mask: `I = a==1`.   `a[I]` is a flat array of those values; `a[I]=...` assigns new values to those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with `np.nonzero(a)`.  However, what's returned from `np.nonzero` is a tuple of elements where each element in the tuple is the indices that are non-zero for a particular dimension.  Specifically, the first element of the tuple are the row locations of what is non-zero, the second element is the column locations of what is non-zero, the third element is the slice locations of what is non-zero, etc.  Therefore, for each grouping of elements in the same index for each tuple element, you get a group of coordinates that tell you which locations are non-zero in your array.

Once you obtain these, you can simply `zip` over them and extract your values:

```
specified = np.nonzero(a)
for (x,y,z) in zip(*specified):
     # do your stuff with a[x,y,z] and x,y,z...
     value = a[x,y,z]
     #....
     #....
```

The above assumes that `specified` has three tuple elements corresponding to `a` being three dimensional.  At each iteration of the loop, we grab unique `(x,y,z)` triplets that correspond to non-zero entries in `a`.  You can go ahead and do your processing on each triplet.

---

However, the above code assumes that you're going to do something with both the `(x,y,z)` triplets and the values themselves within the same `for` loop body.  If it is your intention to extract out the values only, then Boolean indexing is the better way to go.  Specifically, you can just do something like this:

```
values = a == some_value
```

`values` will contain a Boolean array of the same size as `a` that indicates where a value is equal or not equal to `some_value`.  From there, you can perhaps do something like this:

```
a[values] = some_other_value
```

This replaces all values in `a` that equal to `some_value` with `some_other_value`.  If it's your intention to simply access values and do some manipulation on these values, then the above is the better way to go.  However, I can't say that for sure as I don't know what "stuff" you're intending to do inside your `for` loop body.